# Center an image with random resolution to the center of a fixed sized parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an area of 200 height by 320 width which I want to fill it with an image, the image's original resolution can be any. I set a max-height 200px for the parent of the image. As it is now the user can see the first 200px height of the image, but I want 200px on the center of the image. I should not use any jQuery plugin so I wrote the following JavaScript:

```
var offsetHeight = (elem[0].height - 200) / 2;
        if (elem[0].height > 200 && offsetHeight > 0) {
          $(elem).css("margin-top", -offsetHeight);
        }
```

It takes the image's height and reduces it by 200px divides it by 2 and then tries to move the position of the image by this offset to the top, but that doesn't work.

Any idea how can I do that with JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: It will be good if you provide you code through codpen.io or jsfiddle

Comment: can you provide details?

Comment: I will try to reproduce it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image as the background of an element, and then something like this:

```
#imagedemo {
    background:url(https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png) center center; 
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7SrN/2/).

Comment: plus the following: `background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;` will make it better